# How to make login form responsive

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Application uses Bootstrap to create logon form below. In mobile devices logon form is too small, centered in mobile screen, lot of white space. 
It is difficult to enter user's name and password.

How can I fix this so that the login form looks native in mobile phones also ?
Or is there some template which can used to create usable logon form for any screen resolution ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="/admin/css/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/admin/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/admin/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/admin/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>
        Login
    </title>
    <script src="/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/admin/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/admin/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='login-box container'>
        <form action="/admin/Account/LogOn" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user">User</label>
                    <input autofocus="1" class="form-control" id="user" maxlength="10" name="UserName" placeholder="User" required="True" style="width:auto" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="True" style="width:auto" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                        <input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value='Logon' class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML5, Bootstrap 3, jQuery, jQuery UI, ASP.NET MVC 4, and Razor are used.

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap: have you seen the column system? https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ ... Also, you should rename your title to responSIVE, not responSIBLE since that's quite different! :P

Comment: I canged title. I'm using bootstap column system. Logon form has only single column so column system does not help here. I need to make logon  form bigger, maybe to occupy whole screen width in mobile

Comment: I think you must spend some time in bootstrap documentation. And see how this form elements align properly to diff windowsize http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: @chrisv  It looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` was missing

Comment: Yeah, that would probably work too, setting the size to device width. I was thinking you could go more of a responsive way (using the column system to resize for desktop and mobile devices). Then you could use the grid system as I previously was suggesting: https://jsfiddle.net/6x1rr72k/ This way whenever you resize the site, the form will go along! ;)

Comment: Thank you. Great sample. Only difference betweed adding viewport and your sample it that in your sample user field occupies whole width. Actually this is not needed. In my case user id has maximum 10 characters. So fixed width can used always. How to make logon form look more like Android native logon form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```